# Ways to find out div background image is loaded

Tags: javascript, css

I was thinking of where does the difference lies when i try to do the following in two different ways, not in terms of usage, but performance wise affect:

- Using Image tag

  ```
  <img src='http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports/2/'>
  ```

  along with, say,

  ```
  img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  ```
- Using div tag

  ```
  <div class='test'></div>
  ```

  along with, say,

  ```
  .test{
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/300/300/sports/2/'); 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px; 
  }
  ```

Having said that, I wanted to know When image is getting loaded for both cases. For first one, its pretty easy using load event. But for second one, div case, how should i check?..I know of this way [OverHead](http://jsfiddle.net/fu63yngp/), but doesn't it means that it will incur overhead, instantiating `Image` separately for each div?

Are there other possible ways to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener for **onload** event.

> The onload attribute fires when an object has been loaded.
>
> onload is most often used within the  element to execute a
>   script once a web page has completely loaded all content (including
>   images, script files, CSS files, etc.). However, it can be used on
>   other elements as well.

So how you can apply this for the 2 case?

```
$('<img/>').attr('src', 'IMAGE_SOURCE_LINK').load(function() {
   $(this).remove(); 
   $('element').css('background-image', 'url('IMAGE_SOURCE_LINK')');
});
```

Above codes shows only idea of what i mean. Browser will not reload image because they stay in browser memory, and browser load them only once.

Comment: Well, if you would have seen the fiddle, that i have shared, it already considers the approach you have told..But anyways, Thanks for your time.. :)